# ES6 setting this properties with constructor parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I wonder that is there easy way to set this properties with constructor parameters like using spread operator or another way?

this is clasical way of setting props of this:

```
constructor(id=0, name='', surname='') {
  this.Id = id;
  this.Name = name;
  this.Surname = surname;
}
```

I am looking for another way to set this props in one line :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Object#assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to merge an object created from the params to `this`:

```
constructor(id=0, name='', surname='') {
  Object.assign(this, { id, name, surname });
}
```